# vba excel delete data->remain 0

Tags: vba, excel

```
With Range("Q10", Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 .Replace "*-", "", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False
 .Replace " -", "", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False
End With
With Range("X10", Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 .Replace "*-", "", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False
 .Replace " -", "", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False
End With

Dim threeCell As Range
For Each threeCell In Range("Q10", Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With threeCell
    .Value = Trim(.Value)
End With
Next threeCell
```

Hello everyone im using that code to delete data from a column.
That column contains data like "DE-45" "CZ-DZX" and it works perfect it deletes "DE-" and it leaves the cells just with what i want the problem is when a cell is something like this "DE-03" it gives me a "3" instead a "03".

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try formatting the cell as text. This way, Excel number formatting shouldn't shorten `03` to `3`.

Comment: i´ve done that and it doesnt work the macro deletes all the "0"s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit hacky, but it works:

Change `.Replace "*-", "", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False` to:

`.Replace "*-", "'", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False`

Note the single `'` as parameter for `Replacement`. This will result in a value like `'05`, which Excel interprets as String - thus not removing any Zeros.

Comment: It works perfect! but why doesnt it "print" the " ' " ??
THANK YOU!

Comment: `'` is interpreted as "Hey Excel, what comes now is a String! Don't evaluate!". Thus, Excel doesn't apply formatting or formulas. If you might want to begin a cell value with `=` (and not have it evaluated), this is the way.